# Displaying information in a list using regex and .group()

Tags: python, regex

I would like to display a list containing information from some text files using Python.

What I want to display :

```
[host_name, hardware_ethernet_value, fixed_address_value]
```

---

An example of a file (random examples):

```
host name-random-text.etc {

hardware ethernet 00:02:99:aa:xx:yc;

fixed-address 1.3.0.155;

}

host name-another-again.etc {

hardware ethernet 00:02:99:aa:xx:yc;

fixed-address 3.5.0.115;

}
```

---

Someone helped me to write a code for that but it doesn't work anymore, though I know where the problem is coming from.

So the code is as follows :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

#import modules
import pprint
import re

#open a file
filedesc = open("DATA/fixed.10.3", "r")

#using regex expressions to get the different informations


SCAN = {
   'host' : r"^host (\S+) {",
   'hardware' : r"hardware ethernet (\S+);",
   'fixed-adress' : r"fixed adress (\S+);"

}

item = []
for key in SCAN:

#print(key)
regex = re.compile(SCAN[key])
#print(regex)
for line in filedesc:
    #print(line)
    match = regex.search(line)
    #print(match)
    #match = re.search(regex, line)
    #if match is not None:
        #print(match.group(1))
    if match is not None:
        #print(match.group(1))
        if match.group(1) == key:
            print(line)
            item += [match.group(2)]
            break

 #print the final dictionnaries
pp=print(item)

#make sure to close the file after using it with file.close()
```

What should be expected :

```
match.group(1) = host

match.group(2) = name-random-text.etc
```

But what I have is `match.group(1) = name-random-text.etc` so `match.group(2) = nothing here`. This is why the condition `match.group(1) == key` never works, because `match.group(1)` never takes the values `['host', 'hardware ethernet', 'fixed-address']`.

Answer (score 0):

Your reg exp matches only 1 group. 
If you want match 2 groups and `group 1` should be equal SCAN's key, you need change SCAN like this:

```
SCAN = {
   'host' : r"^(host) (\S+) {",
   'hardware' : r"(hardware) ethernet (\S+);",
   'fixed address' : r"(fixed address) (\S+);"
}
```

Comment: Oh, it actually worked ! (is it because you need to differentiate groups with regex ?) Though still not as expected, it only shows the first value ['host_name'] while I want it to show ['host_name', 'hardware_name', 'fixed_adress']

Comment: To fix this issue, please check `loop`. First of all, please fix offset in code `item = [];
for key in SCAN:`
Now this lines are on same level, what incorrect.

Comment: Nevermind, it was a problem of mine, just wrong keys for SCAN like "hardware" instead of "hardware ethernet" to match what's in the files, so I do have ['host_name', 'hardware_name', 'fixed_adress'] now. The problem now is that it displays that only for the first dictionnary of the file not all of them. I think it's mainly because of "break" in the end because when I remove it it takes all the dictionnaries into consideration but only shows their "host_name" in that case. Otherwise I didn't understand why you want me to put ";" after "item = [].

Comment: I can't write this rows in 2 lines in comments. So, I added `;` to separate them.

Comment: Ah ok, but what did you mean by fix offset ? And so the reason I only get a result for the first dictionnary is a problem coming from my loops?

Comment: Lines after ` for key in SCAN:` have same indentation level. It raises following error if execute you code: `regex = re.compile(SCAN[key])
        ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block`

Comment: I added an answer below, you can see how it is on my text editor. PS : Some names might be changed like "final_items" instead of "item" but nothing special.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple, but working decision:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

#import modules
import pprint
import re

#open a file
file_lines = """
host name-random-text.etc {

hardware ethernet 00:02:99:aa:xx:yc;

fixed-address 1.3.0.155;

}

host name-another-again.etc {

hardware ethernet 00:02:99:aa:xx:yc;

fixed-address 3.5.0.115;

}
""".split('\n')


SCAN = {
   'host': r"^host (\S+) {",
   'hardware': r"hardware ethernet (\S+);",
   'fixed_address': r"fixed-address (\S+);",
   'end_item': r"^\s*}$\s*",
}

# Compile only once, if not want repeat re.compile above
for key, expr in SCAN.iteritems():
    SCAN[key] = re.compile(expr)

items = []
item = {}

for line in file_lines:
    for key, expr in SCAN.iteritems():
        m = expr.search(line)
        if not m:
            continue

        if key == 'end_item':
            items.append(item)
            print "Current item", [item.get(x) for x in ['host', 'hardware', 'fixed_address']]
            item = {}

        else:
            item[key] = m.group(1)

print "Full list of items"
pprint.pprint(items)
```

Output:

```
Current item ['name-random-text.etc', '00:02:99:aa:xx:yc', '1.3.0.155']
Current item ['name-another-again.etc', '00:02:99:aa:xx:yc', '3.5.0.115']
Full list of items
[{'fixed_address': '1.3.0.155',
  'hardware': '00:02:99:aa:xx:yc',
  'host': 'name-random-text.etc'},
 {'fixed_address': '3.5.0.115',
  'hardware': '00:02:99:aa:xx:yc',
  'host': 'name-another-again.etc'}]
```

Comment: Okay I see, works great ! Just didn't understand why you wrote`"SCAN[key] = re.compile(expr)"` instead of `"variable_name = re.compile(SCAN[key])"` or `"variable_name = re.compile(expr)"`. 
Sorry for the late answer.

Comment: I described `SCAN` as dict with `string` values. But we need compiled regexp. You can change description to `SCAN = {'key1': re.compile(...), 'key2': re.compile(...)}`, or, use the loop to compile them and update `SCAN`.